# Is it possible to downgrade an XFS filesystem in order for it to be compatible with an older kernel?

Tags: centos, rhel, xfs

### Background

I have a system, where I generate an XFS filesystem image on one system, and then use this image in another system. Currently both use CentOS7 (7.9 and 7.8 respectively). This works reliably.

However, in order to get rid of CentOS once and for all, I am gradually moving to RHEL (and/or Alma Linux).

In a transition period, the 'generator' system will move to RHEL, but I can't change the 'consumer' yet.

### Problem

If I naïvely try to mount the XFS file system (generated by RHEL9) on the CentOS7 system, I get an error message:

```
root@localhost updateFs]# mount -o loop ./fs.img /tmp/fs2/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
[root@localhost updateFs]# dmesg -H | tail -4
[May 5 14:25] XFS (loop0): Superblock has unknown read-only compatible features (0x4) enabled.
[  +0.010671] XFS (loop0): Attempted to mount read-only compatible filesystem read-write.
[  +0.000006] XFS (loop0): Filesystem can only be safely mounted read only.
[  +0.000580] XFS (loop0): SB validate failed with error -22.
```

If I try to mount it read-only, it looks OK. But I need to be able to write to it.

Is there something I can do on either side, to 'downgrade' the filesystem to a more compatible version?

### Versions

| System | distrib | kernel | xfsprogs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Generator | RHEL9.1 | 5.14.0-162.2.1-el9 | 5.14.2-1.el9.x86_64 |
| Consumer | CentOS7.8 | 3.10.0-1127.el7 | 4.5.0-20.el7.x86_64 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that is the relink feature flag, and it would make sense that such a file system could only be mounted read only on a kernel predating this (IMHO very useful) file system feature.

There's no tool to disable that feature after it's been used at file system creation time. You will have to make a new file system and copy over the contents of the old.

```bash
mkfs.xfs -m reflink=0 -f yourfilesystemimage
```

Comment: Thank you - yes, that seems to be the best (only?) option.

Quick follow-up question: Is there a better way to copy the contents of a filesystem (including hard-links etc.) than
`mount -o loop oldfs.img oldfs && mount -o loop newfs.img newfs && (cd oldfs; tar c) | (cd newfs ; tar x)`

Comment: I think that's proper, it preserves hardlinks. Because I tend to forget which options are default in GNU tar, `--xattrs --selinux --acls` is what I typically add to any `tar` invocation. You can probably achieve the same as `tar c | tar x` by doing `xfsdump -J - oldfs.img | xfsrestore -J - newfs/`, but I've never tried that (and it shouldn't be significantly faster than `tar|tar`)

Comment: Reading up a bit more on reflink - this does indeed seem like a _very_ useful feature. Why hasn't it made it into e.g. ext4? I see that patches have been proposed for almost a decade!

Comment: @Popup changing file systems is actually pretty complicated and extremely testing-intense. Don't ask the XFS community how long proposals for subvolumes and snapshots have been around!